# Is there a way to get a website's full title from the Google Custom Search API?

Tags: javascript, json, get, google-search-api, page-title

I'm making a web application that uses the Google Search api, but my problem is that it only gets the first 10ish words from a website's title. Is there any way I could extend to get the whole title, or, a better option, get the contents of the web page and just parse the contents of the `<title>` tag? I'm using pure JavaScript. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make a request to the URL, grab the HTML, and parse out the title from the HTML.

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

httpGet('http://some/url', function(response) {
    // parse the title tag here
});
```